# How to show that $L=\{ wa^kw | w \in \{ a,b,c \}^* ,k \geq 0 \}$ is not regular using the pumping lemma for regular languages?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, pumping-lemma

I'm trying to show that the language in the title is not regular but I don't know how to chose a decomposition $x = abc$ to express the word in the language because the $w \in \{a,b,c\}^*$ is kinda tricky for me, I know it means $ \{ a,b,c\} \cup\{ a,b,c\}^2 \cup ... \cup \{ a,b,c\}^k $ but I don't know how to chose the decompositons for a word in the language and proove that is not in the language by pumping lemma. Any tips ?

Comment: I need help for this example, I understand how to use pumping lemma

Comment: You should probably choose $w$ to contain only $b$s and $c$s so you can tell the difference between $w$ and the $a^k$.

Comment: Good idea @DavidRicherby , let me try it

Comment: @DavidRicherby can i chose w to be of the form $b^j$ or $c^j$ then i would have $x$ a word in L that is of the form $b^j a^k b^j $ then I can show with the pumping lemma that this word is not in the language ? Is that correct ?

Comment: The pumping lemma can't show that a word isn't in the language, and $b^ja^kb^j$ (excellent choice of word, btw) _is_ in the language. Rather, the pumping lemma says "If the langauge was regular, then $b^ja^kb^j$ being in the language would imply that a whole bunch of other words would be in it, too." But we know that some or all of those words aren't in the language, so we conclude that the language isn't regular.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, The Pumping lemma is about regular sets, but "The Pumping Lemma is extremely useful in proving that certain sets are not regular" (Ullman's book, pg.57).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After $n$ is fixed, you could choose $x = b^na^nb^n$. This string is clearly in $L$. By the Pumping lemma $x$ can be written as $uvw$, where $|uv| \leq n$ and $|v| \geq 1$. So for any choice of $u$ and $v$, $uv$ is a string consisting of only $b$s, and so is $v$. Thus $uv^iw = b...b(b...b)^ib...ba^nb^n$ which is not in $L$.

**On @DavidRicherby comment:**

**The Pumping Lemma:**

Let $L$ be a regular set. Then **there is a constant** $n$ such that if $z$ **is any word in** $L$, and $|z| \geq n$ we may write $z = uvw$ in such a way that $|uv| \leq n$, $|v| \geq 1$, and **for all** $i \geq 0$, $uv^iw \in L$.

**How to use**

1) Select the language you wish to to prove irregular.

2) The "adversary" picks $n$, the constant mentioned in the Pumping lemma. Once it has been picked, it may not be changed (fix it).

3) Select a string $z$  in $L$. Your choice may depend implicitly on the value of $n$.

We choose $z = b^na^nb^n$.

4) The "adversary" breaks $z$ into $u$, $v$, and $w$, subject to the constraints that $|uv| \leq n$ and $|v|$.

In my proof the prefix of $z$ consists of $n$ $b$'s, so any choice of $u$, $v$, and $w$ implies that $v$ consists solely of $b$s.

5) You achieve a contradiction to the pumping lemma by showing that **there exists** $i$ such that $uv^iw \notin L$.

Just choose $i=2n$ and we have unequal number of $b$s on the left and right sides of the substring $a^n$: $b^{2n + d}a^nb^n \notin L$.

This is how we prove.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a poor attempt at a pumping lemma proof. "By the Pumping lemma $x$ can be written as $uvw$, where $|uv|\leq n$ and $|v|\geq1$." That's not "by the pumping lemma". Any string of length at least $n$ can be written in that way. The pumping lemma is what lets you conclude that the language isn't regular.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, please first of all correct your comment before you downvote, it is not clear what you write.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, secondly, what is wrong with the proof? Please refresh your knowledge in case you forgot or learn if you don't know at all how to use the lemma. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages

Comment: My comment doesn't need to be "corrected" because it is already correct. The phrase "By the pumping lemma, X" means "Using the pumping lemma, I conclude that X is true". But the thing you state is not a conclusion of the pumping lemma: it's a premise of the lemma. (It's like saying "By Pythagoras, $3^2+4^2=5^2$". That's not "by Pythagoras": it's just arithmetic.) And, rather than just claiming that $b...b(b...b)^ib...ba^nb^n\notin L$, it would be clearer to demonstrate this for a specific $i$ (e.g., $i=0$; note that for $i=1$, the string _is_ in $L$).

Comment: @DavidRicherby, please see updates. As for the wording "By the Pumping lemma", your carping about the introductory sentence "By the Pumping lemma..." is meaningless and not constructive and helpful. After all, it is you who suggested the same idea a bit later after my post.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I dispute your claim that my criticism is "carping", "meaningless", "not constructive" and "not helpful". The distinction between the premise and the conclusion of a lemma are absolutely crucial to mathematics. You have come across as extremely aggressive in your responses to me both here and on another question today. Please do not do that.